# Check if variable type is List<dynamic>, flutter

Tags: dart

Below is the code where I am first printing the type of myVar. It returns `List<dynamic>` in the console. But when I compare its type in a `if` condition, it does not pass this condition.

```
print(myVar.runtimeType);
if (myVar.runtimeType is List<dynamic>) { 
    print("Yes");
}
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`runtimeType` is of type `Type` and never going to be `List` or `int`.

The `is` operator automatically compares `types`.

Also when writing a type, if you leave the generic parameter empty, it will be read as a dynamic. for example `List` and `List<dynamic>` have the same type.

```
if (myVar is List) { 
    print("Yes");
}
```